# Testing equality for each element of two identically structured lists in R: how to be faster

Tags: r, performance, list, purrr

My goal is to get a list which has the same structure as the two initial lists, the difference being that each element is necessarily a logical vector.

Consider two lists:

```
mlist <- rep(list(rep(c(0,2,4),68),c(1),
              sample(x = c("a","b"),size = 1, prob = c(.5,.5))),200)
klist <- rep(list(rep(c(0,2,3),68), c(0),
              sample(x = c("a","b"),size = 1, prob = c(.5,.5))),200)
```

Notice that in a given list, each element is a vector, either string or numeric, and they aren't necessarily the same length. However, both lists have the exact same structure.

The list I am looking for has the same structure and indicates equality for each element within each vector of both lists. For loops provide an unpalatable solution:

```
hon <- as.list(rep(NA ,length(mlist)))
for(i in seq(length(mlist))){
  for (m in seq(length(mlist[[i]]))){
    hon[[i]][[m]] <- mlist[[i]][[m]]==klist[[i]][[m]]
  }
}
```

Another solution, using the purrr package, slightly more elegant, but slower, is

```
han <- map2(klist,  mlist, map2_lgl, identical)
```

Time elapsed is 0.054 for the for loop method, and 0.129 for the purr method. Are there more efficient alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you always vectors as elements of your lists?

If so, you can use the vectorized `==`. Just do

```
hin <- lapply(seq_along(mlist), function(i) {
  mlist[[i]] == klist[[i]]
})

all.equal(hin, hon)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed slightly faster than the for loop.

Comment: Slightly, really? This should be much much faster, normally.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider

```
unlist(klist) == unlist(mlist)
```

but this will discard the list format.

You could determine the original index of each result by comparing to

```
cumsum(lengths(mlist))
```